# Change default db to Master db in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have deleted my default db now I can not login using sql server authentication. How can I change default db back to Master db

**EDIT:**
I cannot login using sql server authentication. It gives me error

> Cannot open user default database.
>   Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'xyz'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   4064)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS: Server->Security->General Tab->Default Database

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I know this option but I can not login and I don't have access to the server from where I can login using Windows Authentication. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Connect via SSMS. In the connection dialog box, click on the "Options >>" button and change the "Connect to database:" option to be Master instead of `<default>`. 
[image]

This should get you in. Then you can use the command below to change your login's default DB.

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='login', @defdb='master'
```